# Completeness of normed linear space

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I came across this question and I had no idea how to proceed.

> Prove or disprove (l<sup>1</sup>, ||.||<sub>2</sub>) is a complete normed linear space.

Here l<sup>1</sup> refers to the vector space of infinite sequences of real numbers X = (x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...) with finite norm ||X||= $\sum_{j=1}^\infty |x_j|$, and ||.||<sub>2</sub> is the two norm.
I have been able to prove that l<sub>p</sub> with p-norm (and thus trivially l<sub>2</sub> with 2-norm) is complete. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that the space is complete we need to show that every Cauchy sequence in the space converges to a limit in the space. Here is a counter-example.

Consider the sequence $\lbrace S_n\rbrace$ defined by

$S_n=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},..,\frac{1}{n},0,0,...)$. The limit of this sequence is $S=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},..,\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1},...)$.

Now the sum $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is convergent, so the partial sums  $\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{i^2}$ form a Cauchy sequence (in $\mathbb{R}$).

It follows that the sequence $\lbrace S_n\rbrace$ is Cauchy in $||.||_2$, since if $m>n$,
$$||S_m-S_n||_2=\sqrt{(\frac{1}{n+1})^2+(\frac{1}{n+2})^2+..+(\frac{1}{m})^2}<\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}}\to0$$ as $n\to\infty$.

For each $n$, $||S_n||_1=\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}$ is a finite sum, and so $S_n \in$ l$^1$.  However the sum $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}$ is not convergent. Hence $||S||_1$ is infinite and so $S\notin$ l$^1$.

The sequence $\lbrace S_n\rbrace$ is therefore a Cauchy sequence in $($l$^1,||.||_2)$ with no limit in $($l$^1,||.||_2)$. The space is therefore not complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped!